# mysql delete from row only if another field is empty or null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php / mysql event lister and I am coming unstuck where I only want to auto delete a record if it's startdate (field_1) has passed and there is no future enddate set (field_5), so field_5 would need to be empty before it's deleted. 
Both start and end date fields are set to null on mysql dbase.
I can get the code to delete a lapsed event using my code below but I have no idea how to apply mysql logic / conditional code required to check if the enddate (field_5) is set or empty, thereby preventing a deletion if that field is set with a string date. Can anyone advise please ?

```
$eventstart ="STR_TO_DATE(field_1, '%m/%d/%Y')";
$eventend ="STR_TO_DATE(field_5, '%m/%d/%Y')";
mysql_query("DELETE FROM events3 WHERE $eventstart < $date ") or  die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add checking if field_5 IS NULL or equal empty string with this code:

```
$eventstart ="STR_TO_DATE(field_1, '%m/%d/%Y')";
$eventend ="STR_TO_DATE(field_5, '%m/%d/%Y')";
mysql_query("DELETE FROM events3 
    WHERE $eventstart < $date AND 
    (field_5 IS NULL OR field_5 ='')"
) or  die(mysql_error());
```

If we need to delete rows with a lapsed set of start and end dates (so both field_1 & field_5 were past current date and warranted deletion) we can use this code:

```
$eventstart ="STR_TO_DATE(field_1, '%m/%d/%Y')";
$eventend ="STR_TO_DATE(field_5, '%m/%d/%Y')";
mysql_query("DELETE FROM events3 
    WHERE $eventstart < $date AND 
    (field_5 IS NULL OR field_5 ='' OR $eventend < $date)"
) or  die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Alexander your code worked a treat, do the curly brackets define a conditional query the same as an IF function ?

Comment: Yes, curly brackets work in the same way. It's just the way to combine your logic condition in appropriate way

Comment: Grateful tx to both you gentlemen as no matter what I googled or tried elswhere on Stack, it seemd to fail and I now see why and that my practices need to change.

Comment: I have just re tried entering a test record with a lapsed set of start and end dates ( so both field_1 & field_5 were past current date and warranted deletion ) but the test record still displays on screen. I further tried it with just the lapsed field_1 start date and it deleted the record. So it appears the logic in field_5 end date is keeping the record from deletion, even after the end date has lapsed, yet the logic is saying it should be deleted ?

Comment: Can you add your sample Sql code to sqlfiddle and give me link to it?

Comment: I will get on sqfiddle later today Alexander but I am wondering if my date var is wrong  $date = "'". date("Y-m-d") ."' ";

Comment: I've changed answer to proper deletion of  test record with a lapsed set of start and end dates ( so both field_1 & field_5 were past current date and warranted deletion )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106130/discussion-between-keithr-and-alexander-polomodov).

Answer (score 3):

I think the logic would be coded as:

```
DELETE e FROM events3 e
    WHERE field_1 <= NOW() AND field_5 is null;
```

I don't see any need for variables in this query.

If you have mistakenly stored the date values as strings, then you would need `str_to_date()`:

```
DELETE e FROM events3 e
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(field_1, '%m/%d/%Y') <= NOW() AND field_5 is null;
```

Storing dates as strings is a bad practice.

Comment: I am begining to realize that storing string dates is as you say a bad practice and tx you for your advice Gordon, I found that Alexanders code worked for me.